# How to mock babel plugin in Jest test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

I am using a babel plugin which provides a function called `myHelper` which is used (but not imported since it is provided as a babel plugin) inside a component I want to test.

How do I "globally" mock `myHelper` with Jest?

Comment: can you provide a sample git repo for this?

Comment: Please always provide a code sample on how you use `MyHelper` in your code

Answer (score 1):

I would let those components accept a `myHelper` property to optionally mock `myHelper` method provided by babel. By default the property would point to the original `myHelper` method:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
      // Use myHelper function like:
      this.props.myHelper();
  }

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myHelper: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  // set by default to babel-provided method
  myHelper: myHelper,
};
```

..and that in your tests using, for example, [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme):

```
const myHelperMock = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent
      myHelper={myHelperMock}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be bad manner, it is possible by making `myHelper` to global.

```
// myHelper.js
function myHelper(){
    return work() // expected 1
}
if (global) {
    global.myHelperFunction = myHelper;
}

// myHelper.test.js
test('TEST MY HELPER', () => {
    expect(global.myHelperFunction()).toBe(1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two directions where yo could go :
- make the helper available globally and test how your code interacts with it
- make the helper available through a `babel-jest` and write your tests accordingly

The first one can be achieved using the `setupFiles` field in the jest configuration : it lets you specify an array of scripts to be executed before your tests are run. You can make your helper globally in one of those.

The second one can be achieved by specifying a `transform` in the jest config. Something like

```
 "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
 }
```

Feel free to comment if your request is more specific.